# ¿Mal resultado?

Tags: c

Buena tarde tengo una pregunta en este código que me proporciono un profesor con apuntadores me dijo que al imprimir z debe ser salir un 3 pero sale un 2 que es como inicializa la variable según mi profesor esta correcto por que a el si le da 3 así tal cual esta el código y ya no entendí por que a mi me da resultado 2 o si es mi compilador que esta arrojando basura del buffer, de antemano gracias.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int x = 0, y =1, z = 2;

    int *iptr;
    iptr = &x;
    *iptr += 1;
    iptr += 1;
    *iptr += 1;
    iptr += 1;
    *iptr += 1;
    iptr += 1;
    printf("%d",z);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Que yo sepa el estándar  no garantiza en ningún momento que las variables se almacenen en  memoria (en la pila en este caso) en el mismo orden en el que son definidas. Esto es tarea el compilador y por tanto dar por sentado esto resulta en comportamientos indefinidos. Incrementas el puntero a int 3 veces, en un mundo sin el gran compañero de todo programador en c/c++ "Undefined_behavior" el puntero apuntaría a z, pero ¿y si el compilador alojó z en otro lado porque le pareció buena idea (y el compilador suele tener buenas ideas para optimizar el uso de memoria y su acceso)?

Answer (score 0):

El resultado enviado "2" corresponde al valor que contiene la variable "z".
La asignación de la memoria se da en tiempo de ejecución, y si bien, puede que se encuentren en forma contigua las definiciones de las variables "x", "y", "z"; el único evento factible de que a través de otra asignación se vea afectado el valor de "z", es si la variable "y" supere el máximo valor asignado para su "tipo de datos en particular", y puede que aun así no tenga cambios la posición de memoria contigua.

Comment: x=000000000062FE44  y=000000000062FE40  z=000000000062FE3C
p=000000000062FE44 x=0
000000000062FE48  x=6487624
000000000062FE4D   y=2147483648 
Y el resultado de z ya no lo da. 
Y él me mostró otros de un compilador en línea 
x=0x7ffd6627f9ec  y=0x7ffd6627f9f0  z=0x7ffd6627f9f4 
0x7ffd6627f9ec  x=0
0x7ffd6627f9f0  x=1
0x7ffd6627f9f4  y=2
0x7ffd6627f9f4  z=3
Y no me explica cuál es la diferencia del por qué no se enlazan en dev así como a él en su compilador en línea.